# Dark mode issue in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, view

I'm developing an app in which i have a switch button in setting , when switch is On i change whole application view to dark mode and when Off it comes to its original view.Now when i turn app to dark mode it changes perfectly but when i click any textfield and keyboard get open it make my whole view dark nothing can be seen no textfield or button, why is it so? My code for making dark them and default theme is this,

```
struct Theme {

static var backgroundColor:UIColor?
static var buttonTextColor:UIColor?
static var labelBackgroundColor:UIColor?
static var labelTextColor:UIColor?
static var buttonBackgroundColor:UIColor?
static var tableViewBackgroundColor:UIColor?
static var tableViewCellBackgroundColor:UIColor?
static var tabBarBackgroundColor:UIColor?
static var imageBackgroundColor:UIColor?


static public func defaultTheme() {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.buttonTextColor = UIColor.black
    self.buttonBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.labelBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.labelTextColor = UIColor.black
    self.tableViewBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.tableViewCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.tabBarBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.imageBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    updateDisplay()
}

static public func darkTheme() {
    self.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2605174184, green: 0.2605243921, blue: 0.260520637, alpha: 1)
    self.buttonTextColor = UIColor.white
    self.buttonBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.labelBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
    self.tableViewBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.tableViewCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.tabBarBackgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.1673184633, blue: 0.3710786104, alpha: 1)
    self.imageBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    updateDisplay()
}

static public func updateDisplay() {
    let proxyButton = UIButton.appearance()
    proxyButton.setTitleColor(Theme.buttonTextColor, for: .normal)
    proxyButton.backgroundColor = Theme.buttonBackgroundColor

    let proxyView = UIView.appearance()
    proxyView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor

    let proxyLabel = UILabel.appearance()
    proxyLabel.backgroundColor = Theme.labelBackgroundColor
    proxyLabel.textColor = Theme.labelTextColor

    let proxyTableView = UITableView.appearance()
    proxyTableView.backgroundColor = Theme.tableViewBackgroundColor

    let proxyTableViewCell = UITableViewCell.appearance()
    proxyTableViewCell.backgroundColor = Theme.tableViewCellBackgroundColor

    let proxyTabBar = UITabBar.appearance()
    proxyTabBar.barTintColor = Theme.tabBarBackgroundColor

    let proxyImage = UIImageView.appearance()
    proxyImage.backgroundColor = Theme.imageBackgroundColor
}
```

}
Now i just call it like this, `Theme.darkTheme()` in app delegate when switch button is On. when dark mode is on and i click textfield and keyboard open it hides the view like this,

[image]

How i can fix that?

Comment: which is it 1. components are there, you just cannot see them. 2. there is a view on top of everything 3.all the components move up out of the screen? try just commenting `proxyView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor` this line

Comment: Try clicking the "Debug View Hierarchy" button in Xcode when you are on your darkened view. You will be able to see all layers of all view that are on your screen in the debugger.